# sine, cosine transformed cyclical features - am I losing information?

Tags: neural-network, feature-engineering, preprocessing

If I use sine, cosine transformation for cyclical features (e.g. weekday or hour of the day), do I lose information if the first ordinal value was 0 respectively?

Assume hours of the day are encoded as follows: 0, 1, ..., 23

If I apply the sine, cosine transformation, I get 23 data points instead of 24 (cf. plot)

[image]

Am I losing information on the first ordinal value (0)?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are 0 and 23 supposed to be the same?

If not then you should use $( \sin(2i\pi/24),\cos(2i\pi/24) )$ instead of $( \sin(2i\pi/23),\cos(2i\pi/23) )$ with $i \in \{0,...,23\}$

Comment: no they are not the same. 0 aggregates the time between 00:00 and 00:59 am, while 23 aggregates the time between 23:00 and 23:59

so the solution you provided is perfect! thank you!